# Why absolutely nothing happens after calling onActivityResult() on the CallbackManager using the Facebook Login Button?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I've been trying to figure out how to solve this but was unsuccessful.

The problem here is after clicking the login button, it loads the Facebook Activity normally, and when it finishes, my activity receives the activity result and notifies the CallbackManager (all as described in the docs).

Unfortunately nothing happens from this point, no method from the registered FacebookCallback is executed, and not even a line is logged to inform of an error.

Here are the involved files:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity

    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    LoginButton loginFacebook;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        ...


        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginFacebook = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginFacebook.setReadPermissions("public_profile","email");
        loginFacebook.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                ...
                (This is never executed)
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                ...
                (Not executed)
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                ...
                (Not executed either)
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(resultCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    ...


}
```

And activity_login.xml includes the button like this

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

I also added the Facebook Activity and APP ID in my android manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

As well as the android app key in the facebook application.

Hope figures out a solution for this, thank you very much.

Comment: Does a dialog asking for permission from user comes out ?

Comment: Yes. When I requested more permissions like birthday, the user would have to accept them. Right now the window appears with a loading icon and disappears automatically soon after.

Comment: Can you debug onActivityResult and see if anything comes in there ?

Comment: Yes: requestCode is 64206, resultCode is -1. The Intent has extras (which I cant access since its a parced facebook object out of my visibility)

Comment: Did you generated your hash key using IDE you are using?

Comment: I tried both from the terminal and from the android application. They match, and that is what I added in the facebook app. (When I had the hash wrong before I would get a message about it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I see now. This is probably wrong

```
callbackManager.onActivityResult(resultCode, resultCode, data);
```

See `resultCode` is entered twice. What you want to do is:

```
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your manifest.xml between application

```
<activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" /><activity
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to show that part of the manifest file. It is there, exactly like that. I'm going to edit my original question and add it.